# Disable touchscreen on Nodewebkit (windows)

Tags: windows, tablet, node-webkit, touchscreen

We are makeing a program in nw that runs on windows 8.1 tablets.
But some users accidentally zoom in because they used 2 fingers (touchscreen zoom).
They don't know how they can zoom out (they are 80+).

So I wanted to disable the zoom function, But I can't find how I can disable it. Is it possible? or is there a hack?

I know how I can disable the pitch zoom. But this isn't realy a pitch zoom.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a touchscreen myself so I can't test it, but adding the following to the HTML should do the trick:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no"/>
```

let me know if it helped..

Comment: Yes, did do the trick. Sorry for the late reply. But thanks for your answer!